# Prove that $∥x + M∥$ is a norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am partially stuck with the following statemant.

Prove that $∥x + M∥$ is a norm if and only if $M$ is closed, where $||x + M|| = inf{|| x + y|| : y \in M}$

The $\leftarrow$ part is solved by first showing that $||x + M||$ is well - defined, then proving the properties which are necessary to be a norm and since $M$ is closed we have $-x \in M$ and thus $x + M = x + (-x) + M = 0 + M$, proving that $|| x + M||$ is a norm.

I just can't figure out the converse part. It sounds very trivially but I think I miss something...
Any help would be grateful.

Comment: This looks like you're missing a lot of details.  In which type of space do we find $x$ and $M$? .... $\|x+M\|$ is a norm on which set? ..... and does $M$ have any special properties? for instance is $0 \in M$?

Comment: X to be a normed linear space and let M ⊂ X be a linear subspace

Comment: Good, that answers the first question and the last two questions [you should edit your question to include these details].  To the middle question that was ignored: $\|x + M\|$ is a norm on which space? [on $X/M$?]

Answer (score 2):

For the opposite direction I think it is useful to look at the converse: if $M$ is not closed, then $\lVert x+M\rVert$ does not define a norm. Assume then that $M$ is not closed, and let $a \in \overline{M}-M$ be a point in the closure. Note that
$$ \lVert (-a)+M\rVert = \inf_{y \in M} \lVert -a+y \rvert =0 $$
directly from the definition of the norm, but $(-a)+M \neq M$ (as $-a \notin M$). This gives us that $\lVert x+M \rVert$ is not a norm.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will give it a try.